# Bubble sort runs in IDLE, but not in uploading system

Tags: python, bubble-sort, nonetype

Conditions are for ascendent or descendent. When I try it in IDLE, it returns right list, but when I try to upload it to get score, it writes: 'None Type' is iterable. What's wrong?

```
def sortNumbers(weights, condition):
    while condition=='ASC':
        for i in range(len(weights)-1):
            for j in range(len(weights)-i-1):
                if(weights[j]>weights[j+1]):
                    weights[j], weights[j+1] = weights[j+1], weights[j]
        return(weights)
    while condition=='DSC':
        for i in range(len(weights)-1):
            for j in range(len(weights)-i-1):
                if(weights[j]<weights[j+1]):
                    weights[j], weights[j+1] = weights[j+1], weights[j]
        return(weights)
```

Comment: That `while` should technically be an `if-else`.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing one of the test cases passes an invalid `condition`, at which point your function returns nothing (`None`), leading to that error. Have you read the question properly to account for all types of `condition`s?

Comment: Tried that already, but that is not a problem. Yeah, there are only two conditions: ASC or DSC

Comment: What about the case?

Comment: Can you show the exact error message. "None Type is iterable" doesn't makes sense. None is actually *not* iterable. What line is throwing the error? While you are at it, show the parameters you are using to test.

Comment: https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/brute/student/view_upload/450993/ae_result/135954